# Solving a differential equation with a residual

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, normed-spaces

Consider the following ODE for $x: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

$x''(t) = \cos x(t)  \, ,$

with $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(0) = 0$.

Now suppose $u:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ solves this equation with some residual $r:I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, i.e. we have

$u''(t) = \cos u(t)+ r(t)\, ,$

with $u(0) = 0$ and $u'(0) = 0$

**My question is:**

If $r: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ becomes "smaller" i.e. goes to $t\mapsto 0$ in the $L^{2}$ norm, can we then conclude that the solution $u$ becomes closer to the solution $x$ with $r(t) = 0$? Or can someone give me a reference to some related literuature?

**My attempt:**

I have tried to apply Euler's method to compute the difference between $x$ and $u$.

Comment: What do you mean with "becomes 'smaller'... in the $L^2$ norm"? Would it be easier to formulate $$u''(t)=\cos u(t)+\epsilon\, r(t)$$ and then consider the asymptotic behavior for $\epsilon\to 0$?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a contractive fixed-point equation $x=T(x)$ with $\|T(x)-T(u)\|<q\,\|x-u\|$ and $q<1$ with fixed point $x^*$ and then consider the perturbed problem 
$$
u = S(u)=T(u)+r
$$
then $S$ has the same Lipschitz constant $q$ and from the Banach fixed-point theorem we know that the distance to the fixed point is
$$
\|x-x^*\|\le\frac{\|x-T(x)\|}{1-q}
$$
so that also
$$
\|x^*-u^*\|\le\frac{\|u^*-T(u^*)\|}{1-q}=\frac{\|S(u^*)-T(u^*)\|}{1-q}=\frac{\|r\|}{1-q}
$$
so that indeed the distance of the solutions is bounded by the size of the perturbation.

Now you only need to find a fixed-point formulation for the differential equation similar to the Picard iteration.